# opencl: how to pass 3d texture from host to device

Tags: opencl

Im porting some CUDA code to opencl 1.2 and In cuda code I have a struct defined as:

```
    struct Info{
    cudaTextureObject_t     in[10];
    cudaSurfaceObject_t     out[10];    
};
```

which I need to pass from host to device.
the device needs to read from `in` and write into `out`.
I'm using `image3d_t` as the the texture/surface data type and intended to use  `write_imagef` for modifying `out`, but `write_imagef` appears to be supported only from opencl 2.0.

are there any other ways I can pass 3d textures to device and be able to modify them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`write_imagef` has been supported since 1.0 for 3D images, but only when the `cl_khr_3d_image_writes` extension is supported by your device. See https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_3d_image_writes.html

Also, `write_imagef` is how you write to an image from your kernel. You title says "how to pass 3d texture from host to device" so you should use `clEnqueueWriteImage` for that.

Comment: thanks . but seems this extension is not supported by all NVIDIA cards . I get :
warning: unknown '#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION' - ignored